# Ability to add "source" to quote?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, markdown, attribution

When people quote others, it is common practice to add a source or attribution of the original speaker. When you select text and hit the quote button, there should be a pop-up that asks for an optional attribution. The attribution should be added and formatted in some way as well.

(While I originally thought of this for English.SE, where it especially applies, I'm posting it here, because it applies to all of the SO/SE sites.)

Answer (score 2):

I would post this as a comment but I want full-blown markdown support :|

So you're suggesting that (to dream up a typeable example)

```
> This is a fancy quote
>@ @drachenstern $2010-11-17Z03:33:13
```

Should turn into something like

> This is a fancy quote 
>    ~ #drachenstern# *9:33 PM*

Where ~ is an indent, # is a distinct shadow background and _ you guys all recognize.

Also note: I'm for this. I'm just spitballing new syntax cos we need to be able to type it out too...

Comment: +1, my only point is that I don't intend to add timestamping, or I wouldn't recommend it, because quotes can come from other sites that arent part of the SE network.

Comment: Good point. I was thinking if you quoted something on the SE network tho.

Comment: Also note: "wait, what? blockquote does italics? `> _italics_` ... wow"